# Multiple selection on list box is not working when mouse is moved from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, mouse, mousemove

hi I'm working on a project in asp.net in which I'm using list box in a td tag of a table whose data will come from object data source. I'm setting Selectmode="multiple" in list box but this is not working but when i won't declare selectmode="multiple", it is working fine for single selection. The problem which i am having with multiple selection is after selecting multiple values either by holding ctl or shift key if i move my mouse from that list box not from the selected item but from entire list box then the values are getting deselected. The list box declaration is

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxAllActions" runat="server" 
             DataSourceID="odsRoleActions" DataTextField="Action_Name"
             DataValueField="Permission_Id" Height="100px" Width="75%"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

The object data source is

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsRoleActions" runat="server" 
                      OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                      SelectMethod="GetAll" 
                      TypeName="WebPortal.Model.Data.RoleActionRepository">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I want to make this list box to work so that the values will be selected even after i remove mouse from it. Help me with this.

Comment: Is the ListBox inside an UpdatePanel? Is there code that causes your page to do a PostBack or partial PostBack when the mouse "exits" the ListBox?  Is there JavaScript attached to the MouseOut event of that ListBox that could be causing problems?

Comment: yes i found the problem. java script is causing the problem. I wrote hover function for each option of list box it is overriding the multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

This problem in my case is caused by JQuery. I wrote a Jquery script to display a hover message for each option of the list box some how this is conflicting the multiple selection of the list box. I replaced jquery script of hover with tool tip then the problem is solved and i'm able to select multiple values but i don't know why hover is not allowing multiple selection.